# How to change icon in requestReview()?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am using `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` to request feedback in my app, however the window shows an old AppIcon that I had in the app.

The icon that is displayed is nowhere to be found in my assets, everything is replaced with the new one.

How can I change it to display the latest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it eventually, was renaming the project and running a new build. It looks like my devices where caching the old icon somewhere, so even re-installing wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this one, this may help you, you need to change app icon in plist.

https://www.propelics.com/customizing-app-icons/

Comment: Thanks for this, but didn't help. I am still seeing the old icon